# Running computations from SWAP without complete performance drop - Discussion on NVMe speeds and if they ever come in reach for RAM replacements

Tags: performance, hardware, swap, ram, nvme

I have been setting up my Linux machine (currently pop-os) in several ways recently to upgrade my system to demands of specific data analysis done in R. In brief: The Data set I am working on is biological single cell data and I'm working on several transformations of large tables in general, as R is not optimized for useful RAM usage and proper garbage collection I always face a huge RAM overhead needed for computation of several well established plugins that I just have to use. So since there is no choice in moving over to less resource heavy computing and I want to use my local PC for cluster like RAM demand, I came to the following setup:

I had 2 8gig 3600mhz cl19 RAMs installed on my Ryzen 5 3600xt running on an MSI tomahawk b450 max, Windows & Linux on a single ssd with 240gb.
I now upgraded further 2x 16gb 3600mhz cl19 RAM sticks getting (interestingly) 50.05 gb of RAM in shown in Linux, and 48 in Windows. I have no issues running this setup so far and still needed more RAM for some small overheads that go above 50gb (sometimes for just a few minutes I'd need ~100gb ram till the next garbage collect loop runs by R during computing a single function).

I Installed a further NVMe (Gen 4 1TB) to an M.2 Gen3 port, and reinstalled both systems to that drive as when using SWAP on the above written setup it'd just lag and not really compute properly anymore (max. 5% CPU usage but system stuck due to full MEM, likely overflow that can't be cached by SWAP).

So with my old 240gb SSD completely setup as one big SWAP I retried to get some big functions run through on my local PC, getting a reasonable functional system for some time even with full RAM, but performance still breaching in the second a CHUNK must be computed from within SWAP.

[image: Here we see usual CPU load; single thread load, using different cores nicely; changing into SWAP computation on just a single old Sata SSD]

I know that this is absolute terror for my ssd drive, however I went further ahead, and added a second swap partition on my NVME and this is where we can finally see the state of the art come in handy: I finally got around 50% performance, second picture just being one example.

[image: From left to right: Full single core performance from RAM, red line; CPU performance drop working on SWAP from SSD (240gig) and NVME (100gig), green line; Task done, system idle but no garbage collect running to free up RAM, blue line; gc() invoke in R to free up RAM, here we see a ca 30gb chunk being freed]

Imagine having efficient NVMes in the future & their performance increases further (RAID 0 for instance does not seem to improve their read speed as shown in several tests that I read into), then running multiple NVMe swap drives might be very suitable to catch large RAM overheads in un-optimized compiles or similar scenarios in which not all of the data is fully required at all times.

Now to my question: Do you think, if I were to run into further RAM limitations, it would be useful to extend a further NVMe via PCIe slot which is still free?
Or is the extend of SWAP files way less powerful than I am thinking here and a thing of the past for most users? Since I have just used Linux for about two years by now I have no real experience with kernel/ deeper involved software whatsoever, on hardware backgrounds even less as you might've noticed.

I'd be looking forwards to hear your opinion with some reasoning so I can read further into these matters, so far I feel this is a niche which not many users ever encounter, yet thought about; but actually I see a lot of potential coming up here for long time demanding computations, maybe even in servers considering the wear out of NVMEs will further be reduced and their efficient is probably lower compared to always on RAM sticks etc...
I hope this is not fully off and too little question to stay here, looking forward to get in touch about it!

ps.: I am also thinking of running a local SLURM one node 'cluster' so I can work on my pc during full usage of the hardware restricted computing node that runs on the very same computer, but that will be a topic for another question.

Comment: Instead of getting an extra NVME for swap, you would be better off replacing the 2x8GB sticks with 2x16GB or even 2x32GB. Swap is useful, and better than crashing due to out-of-memory errors, but it is **never** going to be as fast as RAM (not within the next 5-10 years, anyway). Another option is to figure out if you can split your computation job into multiple smaller jobs that can fit into available RAM...or **if** it is highly parallisable, maybe split it into hundreds/thousands of jobs and run it in your GPU with CUDA or OPENCL

Comment: You may also be able to eke out a **little** more performance with either zram or zswap.  Both of these provide different methods for compressing swap.  zram provides an in-memory block device for compressed swap (so, effectively compressing RAM). zswap is similar but provides a compressed RAM cache for pages written to the swap partition (so, effectively reducing the IO requirements for reading & writing swap). The tradeoff for both is that compression uses some of your CPU power, but if you're swapping a lot that CPU will have lots of idle cycles to spare. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zswap

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I have never read about zswap and will read into it as it seems easily done without further hardware investment, and given my workload I definitely should have cpu load to spare..
Thanks a lot for your estimation, as I have not read posts on (multiple) NVMEs being used to swapout heavy load I thought it may be feasible nowadays, but I will just consider upgrading my 16gb to 64gb so I will have ~100 in total someday.

Since I never ran GPU supported computing it feels rather odd, but thanks for the tip on small tasks! Maybe it will come in handy some day!

Comment: Eventually the benchmarks I ran were already configured on zswap on: in /boot/config-5.15.23.<long_some_numbers>-genric I searched for zswap and it states CONFIG_ZSWAP = Y  further down the setting CONFIG_ZSWAP_COMPRESSOR_DEFAULT_LZO=y is selected though a list of different algorithms is selectable, since my performance runs very nice around now I will leave it as it is, but an interesting excursion to my own kernel settings for sure :)

Comment: Having it compiled into the kernel is only part of what's required.   You also need to configure the system to create and use a zswap device.  Same as you can have support for tmpfs or xfs or whatever compiled in, but that just makes the feature available - it doesn't do anything unless you actually use it.

Comment: I always wanted to do this kind of setup, so I'm glad this work as well as you mentioned. Another couple things you could try: 1. Use Pcie NVME/SSD: when I say this, I do mean the Pcie slot for (usually) your graphic cards or network adapter. Look on youtube for reviews on other website for benchmark, but I believe it will be faster than Sata or normal M.2 NVME speed. 2. Don't use PopOS! or just use a window manager instead of DE (Gnome in this case is used if I recall). I used it and I noticed PopOS use a lot more ram, especially when idle. It should use around 200-500MB max with just a WM.